# Oracle query with "in clause" - how to speed up using an index?

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing, in-clause

I got a oracle query that uses an in-clause with eight given values, like:

```
select * from mytable a 
where a.wf_type in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'value7', 'value8');
```

The table is not really big (about 3 million rows) and the query does a full table scan.
Therefore I added an index for the wf_type attribute.
But the index is not used by the query with the in-clause. If I change the query to one specific value like

```
select * from mytable a where a.wf_type = 'value1';
```

the index is used and the query runs fast.
How do I fasten the query with the in-clause? Is it possible by using an index or are there other ways?

Comment: What is the table definition including indexes?

Comment: It depends on selectivity. You can easily check it using `select count(*), count(case when a.wf_type in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6', 'value7', 'value8') then 1 end) from my_table a` and compare costs of the queries with and without a hint: `/*+ index(a(wd_type)) */ `

Comment: How many **distinct values** of `wf_type` in the table?

Comment: There are only 47 distinct wf_type values in the table. I could find the reason why the index is not used: to the select statement in production an additional where-clause is added. I did a test with an index including both attributes (wf_type and the additional attribute). The query is now quick and uses the index. Sorry for the incomplete information above.